# Clicking help on Time Machine "to improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you" message cancels it?

Tags: macos, time-machine, error, documentation

On a fairly new machine running 10.8.3 I'm getting the message:

> **Time Machine completed a verification of your backups on “<disk>”. To improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you.**
>
> Click Start New Backup to create a new backup. This will remove your existing backup history. This could take several hours.
>
> Click Back Up Later to be reminded tomorrow. Time Machine won’t perform backups during this time.

with three buttons: <kbd>?</kbd> <kbd>Back Up Later</kbd> <kbd>Start New Backup</kbd>

When I click <kbd>?</kbd> to get more information, the dialog is dismissed and nothing (apparent) happens.  The dialog comes up again when I manually trigger a backup, so it looks like whatever happened was the equivalent of clicking <kbd>Back Up Later</kbd>.  I'm able to repeat this every time the dialog comes up: clicking <kbd>?</kbd> dismisses it instead of bringing up any help.

When I click, in `/var/log/system.log` I see:

```
Apr 10 16:43:05 blahdiblah.local com.apple.backupd[31047]: Recovery backup declined by user.
Apr 10 16:43:05 blahdiblah com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[247] (com.apple.UserNotificationCenterAgent[31120]): Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 10 16:43:05 blahdiblah.local ReportCrash[31920]: Saved crash report for UserNotificationCenter[31120] version 3.3.0 (28) to /Users/blahdiblah/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/UserNotificationCenter_2013-04-10-164305_blahdiblah.crash
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah.local com.apple.SecurityServer[17]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [11] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [11] (100012,0)
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah.local com.apple.backupd[31047]: Backup canceled.
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah.local com.apple.backupd[31047]: Ejected Time Machine network volume.
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_unmount: /Volumes/Time Machine, flags 0, pid 31922
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_unmount : We are the last mnt/sbmnt using volume /Volumes/Time Machine 0xffffff81c7084008
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah kernel[0]: ASP_TCP do_thread_read: no reqInfo found for reqID 9
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_unmount : We are the last volume using socket /Volumes/Time Machine 0xffffff81c7084008
Apr 10 16:43:06 blahdiblah kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_unmount : afpfs_DoReconnect sent signal for unmount to proceed
```

**Is anyone else getting this bug?**

**Does anyone know what the help button *should* link to?**

This isn't the first time that this has come up, and while I've seen discussions about it here and elsewhere on the web, I'd like to check the Apple docs too.  While I'm interested in fixing the underlying problem causing my backups to need to be fixed too, in the immediate I just want to confirm this bug and find the link to Apple's documentation.

Comment: This knowledge-base article: [OS X Mountain Lion: If you see a message that you must create a new backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11310) (or a local copy) is *probably* what that help should be linking to, but it'd be nice to hear confirmation from anyone else.